# How to design the spring boot JPA Model classes in below situation?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am having some catalogs, under these catalogs there are some categories some catalogs doesn't have any categories at all and finally there are products under various categories or catalogs.

for example **catalog **Household**** will have a **category Kitchen** which then will have **products like oven, plates, dishwasher** etc while **product bed-sheets will directly belong to catalog households and not to any category**

same way **catalog chemicals will not have any category and will only have products**.

below things are certain

**i) All the products belongs to some catalogs**

**ii)  some catalogs will have categories and then categories will have products**

**iii) some products will only belong to catalogs and never associate with any category**

I have come up with below Model classes structure but I am not sure that How they will handle the above case , can you please suggest something ?

```
@Entity
public class Catalogs {

    @OneToMany(CascadeType.All, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "catalogs_id")
    private Set<Categories> categories;

     /* rest of the code will go here */
}
```

my categories class will be like this

```
@Entity
public class Categories {
    
  @OneToMany(CascadeType.All, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id")
    private Set<Products> products;  
}
```

finally my Products class will go like this

```
@Entity
public class Products {

     /* Products related codes */
}
```

**or** should I also have a field for products in my catalog class ?
like below

```
 @Entity
public class Catalogs {
    @OneToMany(CascadeType.All, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "catalog_id")
    private Set<Categories> categories;

    @OneToMany(CascadeType.All, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "catalog_id")
    private Set<Products> products;


     /* rest of the code will go here */
}
```

Comment: I posted an answer that you can check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement, I got an approach in my mind. If I start from **Catalog**, I would consider that class as root. Then I would design that class as

```
@Entity
public class Catalogs {

// just catalog name or other activity. not mapping

}
```

After that one, I would design category class like this, where every category would be under a **catalog**.

```
@Entity
public class Categories {

// other attribute...
    
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "catalog_id")
    private Catalogs catalogs;  
}
```

After these, I would design my product class like this. As you said one product may be under catalog or maybe under a category. So I made some attribute nullable.

```
@Entity
public class Products {
    
    //other attributes....
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "catalog_id")
    @Nullable
    private Catalogs catalogs;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    @Nullable
    private Categories categories;
}
```

Check this approach. And response about your opinion.

Comment: Thankyou very much Avijit Barua, I will try this and comment again with inputs

Comment: @Gaurav, Ok, let me know after trying.

Comment: I gave you upvote Avijit but unfortunately my reputation is not enough to show it :-)) thankyou again for an elaborate answer :-)